# What is implied by "The Thirteenth Floor" finishing with a "TV shutdown" efffect?

Tags: the-thirteenth-floor

The movie *The Thirteenth Floor* finishes in a "TV shutdown" kind of way. Does this imply that even though Douglass Hall

> escaped from the system that is in the 1990s to the "real world" in 2024, the future is another system as well?

Comment: Does my answer here not answer your question? http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28868/why-is-the-original-self-lost-through-death-in-the-13th-floor-and-replaced-by

Comment: Searching did not pop up that question, I read your answer but I did not understand it to be honest. Could you elaborate more in an answer here?

Comment: I'll let Richard write up his own answer, but basically, yes, Richard says that the future world is a simulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually an alternate ending, that does not display that scene.

The scene that you described is not in the original script. Is not uncommon that the studio makes requests for changes (on behalf of a more *comercial* approach for the movie).

With or without the scene, you could still raise the question about

> if 2024 is a simulation or not. And the world in the upper level, is a simulation too, like an endless [Russian doll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll)? How would I make sure I reached "*the top*", "*the real thing?*".

As with other sci-fi works that deal with the perception of reality, like [*Ubik*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubik) or [*The Three Stigmata of Palmer Eldritch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Three_Stigmata_of_Palmer_Eldritch) the appropriate question of a character in that world would be "**how do I tell what is real and what is not?**", "**How could I be sure?**".

That ending is just an artifact to bring some of that reflection. Even,

> that abrupt disconnecting could tease the spectator: "*how could you be sure your world is not a simulation too?*"